# How can I create a stack of images offset and overlapping each other?

Tags: css

I'm attempting to show a stack of cards and I want the top of each to show and to allow the user to hover over the card to expose it. I have the following CSS, but for any number of cards I want to display I have to copy my nth-child section. I'm not currently using LESS or Style, but they are options if one of them can do this. To be clear I am looking for a solution that works with any number of cards.

```
.card_container > {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.card_container > .card {
  position: absolute;
}

.card_container > .card:nth-child(1) {
  z-index:1;
  top:0px; 
}
.card_container > .card:nth-child(2) {
  z-index:2;
  top:35px; 
}
.card_container > .card:nth-child(3) {
  z-index:3;
  top:70px; 
}
.card_container > .card:hover {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

I tried using javascript to assign the styles, but then the style assigned directly to .card takes presedence over the .card:hover.

```
  $('.card').each(function(index, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.css('z-index', index);
    $el.css('top', (35*index)+'px');
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operate on containers rather than the cards.  Not overly intuitive but very simple.

```
.card_container li {
  height: 35px; 
  z-index: 0;   
  position: relative;    
}

.card{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;  
  position: absolute;
}

.card_container li:hover {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

​The hovered card will show as overflowing content on top of the other cards due to the z-index.

Comment: Thanks. I created a fiddle testing/demonstrating your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/BrAbs/1/

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Nc7FC/) fiddle might give you a direction. Basically you nest ul inside each other and the give each a position which is calculated relative to its father:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="card"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="card"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="card"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul ul{
 position:absolute;  
 top:10px;
 left: 10px;   
}
.card{
 background: red;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;    
}​
```